# Importance of research experience in engineering PhD

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate, engineering

My friend would like to achieve a Doctorate in Engineering, however currently has only limited research experience (She has completed an undergraduate degree and helped a few professors with some of their side projects).  While I know that research experience is rather important for many science PhD programs, does the same apply to Engineering?

My thought is that since most engineering undergraduate programs are more industry based, research experience is less common and therefore less demanded.  Is this hunch true, or would it be best to get a Master's Degree with the associated research experience, and then apply for a doctoral program?

Comment: Why doesn't she apply to PhD programmes and see if she is accepted? Apply to some Master's degrees at the same time as a fallback: win win.

Comment: A PhD is still an academic degree requiring research experience. Some universities offer a DEng, which is the professional equivalent. In many UK and Australian universities, there are pathways to take as interim steps to transition into the PhD if the applicant doesn't have enough research experience. These take the form of MPhil/MEng degrees that articulate to the PhD. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think that not having undergraduate research experience wouldn't be disqualifying in any field. The best place to learn, however, is from the admissions system of a university you are considering attending. The expectations can vary.

The doctorate, in fact, is where you normally get qualified as a researcher. Masters programs will often, but not necessarily, have a research component, depending on field of study. But even at that level, the usual goal is to produce practitioners of an art/craft/profession rather than researchers. If practitioners don't normally need to do research, the Master's degree may not have much of a research component.

Another issue is "What constitutes research?". If you help out, for pay or credit on someone else's research you may learn relatively little about conducting research, even though you are listed as a co-author on some publications. At the minimum it is hoped that you learn a bit about common processes and the tools and techniques, but *the research would then be driven by the ideas of others*. Perhaps in Chemical Engineering, having this basic knowledge of the tools would be expected but unlikely to be gained in an undergraduate education.

On the other hand, at many universities, the competition for enrollment in any given program can be fierce and some research background may be taken as a plus, separating the "obviously qualified" from the "rest of the best." The timing of application can also have an effect. If the country has a large need and few applicants you will have a better chance than in the opposite situation.

Whether to take a separate Master's level degree or not, depends on the university and possibly the country. Taking a Master's that doesn't have a research component won't necessarily help. Also, many doctoral programs will accept students with only an undergraduate degree and, perhaps, award a Master's along the way. In that case, expect the overall program to be a bit longer than if you start with an appropriate Master's, of course.

Finally, if you take a Master's at one university, you still need to contend with admission requirements at a second university if you switch. In those places in which programs are well coordinated this may be simple. In others, not so simple, so study the issue in advance wherever you are.

The best advice is to look at the requirements of a few interesting universities. If you seem to have the qualifications, explore further, perhaps by corresponding with the department you wish to join or the university itself. If you are encouraged to apply then you probably have the basic qualifications, though you still face the competition.

Answer (score -1):

This may depend on the location - in the UK, it is possible to be enrolled on a MPhil / PhD program and part-way through officially transfer to the PhD.